# How to send a value from one component to another?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I make a componenet in which I have one input field and button.On click of button I am diplaying the second component.I want to send data from one component to another component ?

how I will send data from one component to another ..I need to send input value (what ever user type in input field ) I need to show on next component or next page .On button click .how to send data ?
here is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/IINX8Zq8J2LUTIyf4DYD?p=preview

```
import {Component,View} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
})


export class AppComponent {
   toDoModel;
  constructor(private _router:Router) {


  }

  onclck(inputValue){
    alert(inputValue)
    this._router.navigate(['Second']);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Oh!! may be I' m too late to answer the question! 
But never mind.This might help you or other to share data between components using Router,Shared-Service and Shared-object used withing shared-service. I hope this will surely help.

[Answer](http://plnkr.co/edit/RRE6rGGVkHrgTIwzdXxc?p=preview)

**Boot.ts**

```
import {Component,bind} from 'angular2/core';

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {Router,ROUTER_PROVIDERS,RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,APP_BASE_HREF,LocationStrategy,RouteParams,ROUTER_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/router';

import {SharedService} from 'src/sharedService';

    import {ComponentFirst} from 'src/cone';
import {ComponentTwo} from 'src/ctwo';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
    <h1>
      Home
    </h1> 

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      `,

})

@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/component-first', name: 'ComponentFirst', component: ComponentFirst}
  {path:'/component-two', name: 'ComponentTwo', component: ComponentTwo}

])

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(router:Router)
  {
    this.router=router;
  }

    ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit'); 
    this.router.navigate(['/ComponentFirst']);
  }



}

    bootstrap(AppComponent, [SharedService,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue(location.pathname)
    ]);
```

**FirstComponent**

```
import {Component,View,bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {SharedService} from 'src/sharedService';
import {Router,ROUTER_PROVIDERS,RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,APP_BASE_HREF,LocationStrategy,RouteParams,ROUTER_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
  //selector: 'f',
  template: `
    <div><input #myVal type="text" >
    <button (click)="send(myVal.value)">Send</button>
      `,

})

export class ComponentFirst   {

  constructor(service:SharedService,router:Router){
    this.service=service;
    this.router=router;
  }

  send(str){
    console.log(str);
    this.service.saveData(str); 
    console.log('str');
    this.router.navigate(['/ComponentTwo']);
  }

}
```

**SecondComponent**

```
import {Component,View,bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {SharedService} from 'src/sharedService';
import {Router,ROUTER_PROVIDERS,RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,APP_BASE_HREF,LocationStrategy,RouteParams,ROUTER_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
  //selector: 'f',
  template: `
    <h1>{{myName}}</h1>
    <button (click)="back()">Back<button>
      `,

})

export class ComponentTwo   {

  constructor(router:Router,service:SharedService)
  {
    this.router=router;
    this.service=service;
    console.log('cone called');
    this.myName=service.getData();
  }
  back()
  {
     console.log('Back called');
    this.router.navigate(['/ComponentFirst']);
  }

}
```

**SharedService and shared Object**

```
import {Component, Injectable,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'

// Name Service
export interface myData {
   name:string;
}



@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  sharingData: myData={name:"nyks"};
  saveData(str){
    console.log('save data function called' + str + this.sharingData.name);
    this.sharingData.name=str; 
  }
  getData:string()
  {
    console.log('get data function called');
    return this.sharingData.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what exactly i was looking for.Thanks God i found this solution.
Thanks @micronyks for this answer. :) :)

Comment: @ananya that's great it helped you.

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do is make a service, inject it in both the components, assign the input value to the service veriable and access it in the other component.
Sorry bro but don't know to create plunker. Here is the code :

EDIT :

First make this data service :

```
export class DataService{
     dataFromService;}
```

Then inject this in your first component :

```
import {Component,View} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {DataService} from 'path/to/dataservice';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
})


export class AppComponent {
 toDoModel;
 constructor(private _router:Router, public dataService : DataService) {


}

 onclck(inputValue){
  alert(inputValue)
  this.dataService.dataFromService = inputValue;
  this._router.navigate(['Second']);
 }

}
```

Then inject in another component and access the value :

```
import {Component,View} from 'angular2/core';
import {DataService} from 'path/to/dataservice';
export secondComponent{
   constructor(public dataService : DataService){
   console.log(this.dataService.dataFromService);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its always better to have a backend and a service calling backend to get data .
first you need to post the input data to service and get that data from some database through nodejs or database.
That would be the nicest way to get that based on some primary key of the data
atleast how enterprise apps work in reality