# How can a child-component to subscribe to event emitted from a parent-component?

Tags: angular

I have a parent-component that contains a form that submits data to the server.  I want to hand server errors to a child component that displays the errors.

Can I have the child-component subscribe to an "OnError" event fired by the parent?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803565/how-to-send-a-value-from-one-component-to-another it might help.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: @EricMartinez: Thanks! That was what I was looking for...