# In AngularJS 2 what is way to manage input/output properties between parent and child component when calling child using route-config

Tags: angular

I am creating an application using AngurarJS 2, where I created a parent component "LayoutComponent" and various child components are called using `@RouteConfig`. As below:

```
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, name: 'Dashboard', useAsDefault:true, data:{page:this.page} },
{ path: '/projects', component: ProjectListComponent, name: 'Project.list' },
{ path: '/project/:id', component: ProjectDetailComponent, name: 'Project.detail' },
{ path: '/project/add', component: ProjectAddComponent, name: 'Project.add' },
// { path: '/login', component: UserLoginComponent, name: 'User.login' },
{ path: '/logout', component: UserLogoutComponent, name: 'User.logout' },
{ path: '/users', component: UserListComponent, name: 'User.list' },
{ path: '/user/profile', component: UserProfileComponent, name: 'User.profile' },
{ path: '/user/:id', component: UserDetailComponent, name: 'User.detail' },
{ path: '/calendar', component: CalendarMainComponent, name: 'Calendar.main' },
{ path: '/emails', component: EmailListComponent, name: 'Email.list' },
// { path: '/user/register', component: UserRegisterComponent, name: 'User.register' },
])
```

I am using a layout template in LayoutComponent as template. I placed a tag `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in layout template where all child components render their views. Now I want to update some value from child component to layout component's view (e.g. "title"). When we call child components by using `directives` then we can pass objects as `inputs` in child components and when we make any change in that object within child component, the changes reflects to parent component and related view reflects.

But I am not able to do this when calling child component using `@RouteConfig`. So I need help in this regard.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I want to tell that I tried to solve my problem by using a shared service object as bellow:

I created a service `PageService` and injected it into parent component.
I passed it in constructor of LayoutComponent and assign it as component's `page` property.
I used this "page" property in component's template to show value.

Now when I am updating value of service object's properties, I am getting change detection exception which stops further execution of script:

> EXCEPTION: Expression '{{page.brdcrmb.title}}
>                    in LayoutComponent@223:37' has changed after it was checked

Comment: here is router-outlet tag between inverted commas>> I placed a tag "" in layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a value from one component to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803565/how-to-send-a-value-from-one-component-to-another)

Comment: I updated my answer. I had a typo that made it say quite the opposite of what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Components added by the router can't take part in declarative data binding with their parent component. For this usually a shared service is used to share data between the added component and a ancestor component.

See [How do i share data between components in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular2) for more details.