# How to pass json object one component to another component in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-components

How to pass `JSON` object one component to another component. I have two components LoginView and ProfileView. I got particular user details in LoginView component. I want to pass `this.result` and `this.studentresult` to ProfileView component, basically after login I am trying to pass user details to user profile page. How can I do this, help me out, I am new to angular.

i gone through [How to send a value from one component to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803565/how-to-send-a-value-from-one-component-to-another)

but in my case i want to call 3 api's in LoginView component and i need to pass all these api result to ProfileView component

**LoginView component**

```
export class LoginView {      
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}      
    ngOnInit() {}      
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user/1')
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
                this.result = response;
            }    
        }
     this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/student/1')
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
                this.studentresult = response;
            }    
        }

}
```

**ProfileView component**

```
export class ProfileView {    
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}    
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the views? Are they just different pages?

Comment: you can use a service that hold the data, and you can consume that service from both components

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a value from one component to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803565/how-to-send-a-value-from-one-component-to-another)

Comment: Yes different pages @ BradleyDotNET

Comment: help me on this @SibeeshVenu

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Shared Service, set a variable on LoginView and read it on ProfileView.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
    userData;
    constructor(){
      this.userData= {};
    }
    setUserData(val: object){
      this.userData= val;
    }
    getUserData(){
      return this.userData;
    }
}
```

LoginView component

```
export class LoginView {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user/1')
      .subscribe((response:any) => {
        this.result = response;
        this.sharedService.setUserData(response);
       }
}
```

ProfileView component

```
export class ProfileView {

  constructor(sharedService: SharedService) {
  console.log(sharedService.getUserData());
  }
  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Comment: if i have two or three api i call in LoginView component that time what can i do ??

Comment: In this case you need to use EventEmitters, subscribe and emit events. 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LoginView  -> SharedService]: 

  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LoginView  -> SharedService]: 

    NullInjectorError: No provider for SharedService!

Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LoginView  -> SharedService]: 

  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LoginView  -> SharedService]: 

    NullInjectorError: No provider for SharedService!

    at _NullInjector.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js._NullInjector.get (core.js:1002)

Comment: You need to provide your new service.

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services

Answer (score -1):

Use `Observable.forkJoin` for your requests and then use a shared service to pass the data between the components. I like to use `BehaviorSubjects` to share data between components that are not related in any way....

Service:

```ts
// behaviorsubject wants an inital value
private mySubject = new BehaviorSubject([]);
public mySubject$ = this.mySubject.asObservable();

setValue(value) {
  this.mySubject.next(value);
}
```

Provide this service at module level, not component.

And then as said, use Observable forkjoin to execute the requests in parallel. That produces an array of your result with content in the order you provided, which you can pass to your other component through your service:

(case: not using pipeable operators):

```ts
let user = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user/1');
let student = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/student/1');

Observable.forkJoin([user, student]).subscribe(data => {
   this.myService.setValue(data);
});
```

Then in your other component you subscribe to the observable:

```ts
this.myService.mySubject$.subscribe(data => {
  this.user = data[0];
  this.student = data[1];
});
```