# Pass value from one template to another

Tags: angular

I am newbie @angular but I am unable to see any hints on that how to pass `Input` varliable from one component to another. I have a card which took `json` object as input and I am able to print `{{ json.name }}` on that template, but I am unable to pass `json.name` to child component:

```
  <nb-card-header>
    {{ cardDetails.name }}
  </nb-card-header>
  <ngx-gauge-chart [name]=cardDetails.name></ngx-gauge-chart>
```

gauge chart component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-gauge-chart',
  styleUrls: ['./summary-card.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <div echarts
         class="echart"
         [options]="options">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class GaugeChartComponent implements OnDestroy {
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.alive = false;
    }
    @Input()
    name: string;
  private alive = true;
  options: any;
  themeSubscription: any;

  constructor(private theme: NbThemeService) {
    this.themeSubscription = this.theme.getJsTheme().subscribe(config => {
    this.options = {
      series: [
        {
          startAngle: 180,
          endAngle: 0,
          thick: 15,
          type: 'gauge',
          showSymbol: false,
          data: [{value: 55, name: this.name}],
          axisLabel: {
            show: false,
          },
        },
      ],
      };
    });
  }

}
```

can anyone give me a hint how to pass `cardDetails.name` so It can be read as an Input on `ngx-gauge-chart` component?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Could you provide more details?

Comment: I think this will be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803565/how-to-send-a-value-from-one-component-to-another

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr I put gauge chart component code

Comment: It should works. Could you provide Stackblitz?

Comment: it shouldn't  if this.theme.getJsTheme() return sync observable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you try  to access to input parameter in constructor. Just  move whole code from it  to `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about [Life Cycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

- **Constructor** is called when a new instance of a class is created.
- All lifecycle hooks including **ngOnInit** are called as part of the following change detection phase. Usually a component initialization logic requires either some DI providers or available input bindings or rendered DOM
- The **@Input** communication mechanism is processed as part of following change detection phase so input bindings are not available in constructor.

Therefore it didn't work when you had it in constructor.